# How to install OCX components of an application?

Tags: vb6

I have copied some components on an App server so that I can run a VB6 application

```
TABCTL32.OCX
TABCTL32.DEP
MSWINSCK.DEP
MSWINSCK.OCX
MSMAPI32.DEP
MSMAPI32.OCX
FTP.OCA
FTP.OCX
COMDLG32.OCX
```

I took some advice from the answer of another question on here.  Can anyone advise if it is safe to do this.  There is an ASP.NET application (framework version 3.5) installed on this server as well.

Comment: What is the question? Safe in what sense?

Comment: I don't know about .DEP files, but I do know that .OCA files are simply temporary caches that will be regenerated from the corresponding .OCX files if they are absent, so you can probably leave out FTP.OCA

Comment: Copying .OCX files won't be enough; you'll need to regsvr32 each one...

Comment: You will need to RegSvr32 the OCX's before they can be used on the new machine.

Comment: @Ganesh R, safe in the sense that it will not cause an error like the blue screen of death.  I come from a Java background and don't have a great deal of experience with System32 folder.

Comment: @David W, I copied the files to the system32 folder (I didn't register them).  The application that uses them is registered in the System32 folder (myApp.DLL).  Do they still need to be registered? I don't think they do.

Comment: @w0051977 As David and nonnb mentioned, just copying them to system32 folder will not do (if they expose COM Servers). You will have to run regsvr32 and register these ocx files. Now if these ocx are custom ocx files, then you should be good. But if they are a 3rd party ocx and the machine already contains a more recent version of the ocx, then regsvr32 will override the newer registration with the older dlls. This may cause an issue. In case this is the only server available, take a System 1 restore point and try out the ocxs. Else use a separate machine for using the VB6 application.

Comment: Yes, they do have to be registered. An .OCX is a COM DLL that must make itself known to the system via registering its class ID's and other related information, or the apps that expect them to be available will simply fail/crash, as there will be nothing that maps the ProgId/ClassID's used in the app to the control that supplies them.

Comment: @David W, I think I understand what you mean.  Are you saying that copying the files to the system32 folder will allow the app to run without an error appearing like: "component not found", but then when the app tries to use the component it will fail? Are you able to post this in an answer so that I can give credit?

Comment: @w0059177 Done as requested :) Hope that helps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Files ending with an ".OCX" extension are actually 32-bit in-process COM DLL's that must be registered in order for them to be used. This is accomplished via the command-line "regsvr32" utility.

Copying these files to the application's host directory will not be adequate to allow the application relying on the components provided in the .OCX files to access them. This is because applications will create instances of COM objects via their registered programmatic ID ("ProgID"), that Windows will, in turn, translate to the CLSID and COM in-process server DLL that provides the implementation for the object(s). If the OCX isn't registered, there's no COM information to allow Windows to perform the required mapping.

The ProgID's, ClsID's, and related type library informatoin are "published" to Windows via the RegSvr32 utility, which really just loads the target DLL/OCX and specifically calls the COM DLL entry point "DllRegisterServer," which allows the DLL to publish its COM registration information. If this is not done, no COM registration is available, and calls for the objects hosted in the OCX/DLL will fail.

The absence of the vital COM registration information is the reason copying OCX files to the host folder is not sufficient for the consuming application to leverage the COM objects hosted therein.

**Additional information re file extensions**

- .OCX - In reality, it's just a COM DLL with a different extension. These names were given as containers for VB extensions under the old "**O**LE **C**ontrol E**x**tension" moniker, hence OCX.
- .DEP - Windows Dependency files. These files, which tend to have a Visual Basic "Setup application" heritage, typically contain information about the dependencies a given EXE or DLL has on other DLL's. For example, A.EXE may depend on B.DLL, but B.DLL may also depend upon C.DLL.
- .OCA - OCX type library cache. This is typically constructed on the fly, and is rebuilt when needed.

Comment: Thanks +1 for the reference to Prog IDs.  Can you explain why I am able to run the app without registering them i.e. by only copying them?

Comment: The likely probabilities are that the OCX's already exist elsewhere on the system, and were registered previously, or while the application may well have started, the elements of the application that use the objects hosted in the OCX's has not been exercised.

Comment: Could it be that they were registered and then deleted?

Comment: Not if the program is actually running and objects known to be hosted in those DLL's are being exercised. The registration, ultimately (among the other COM information explained above), points to the location of the files that are responsible for creating the objects, so if those files are deleted from the location to which they've been registered, an app calling for objects from them will fail/crash.

Comment: Thanks.   I transferred the VB6 project from another server.   I suspect the previous developer had the VB6 project installed on the server I have transferred to many years ago and then moved it.  Could this be why the files are registered but deleted?

Comment: If another developer had installed the application, but just deleted the core executable, it would certainly have left the ancillary dependencies behind. Deleting the files does not remove the COM registration information. If the app is actually running, seems likely the files are hiding out there somewhere.. :)

Comment: Finally can you explain what the file extensions are or provide a link to somewhere that does.  I have experience with .EXE and .dll.

Comment: Surely. Let me modify the answer to put the information in there.

Comment: Explaining the "just works" phenomenon: VB6 executables do auto-registration of OCX files of all controls placed on a form/usercontrol upon loading it. This happens only if these constituent controls are not already registered, if using the same file names as during compile-time, if the these files can be loaded be a `LoadLibrary` call (so this includes exe folder), if current user has admin privileges (because VB6 compiled OCXs can register in HKLM only)

Comment: @wqw Excellent point. Completely escaped me. All that VB6 stuff is finally really leaving my head after all these years :)

Comment: @wqw, can you post what you have said as an answer so that I can give some credit? Are you saying that the OCX files will be automatically registered if an application calls them and the OCX is not already registered?

Comment: @David W, could you clarify what you mean by "excellent point".  Does VB6 automatically register the OCX files?

Comment: @David W, my question isn't fully answered yet.  I have upvoted your answer? I don't understand your last comment.

Comment: Previous comment deleted. It will register them if it can find the .OCX in one of the standard file path locations..

Comment: Thanks.  That was the answer I was looking for all along.

Comment: Sorry amid all the other info I simply had forgotten about the auto registration. Brain cramp :)

Comment: DO NOT just dump ActiveX libraries into an application's folder and let the prorgam try to register them after finding them via DLL Search.  This "style" of "deployment" will lead to you breaking other appliations on the system which used the same shared libraries.

Answer (score 2):

If you really want to achieve side-by-side deployment of these OCXs (and DLLs) without resorting to VB6 auto-registration hack, best would be to use an application manifest for registration-free COM.

We are using [UMMM](https://github.com/wqweto/UMMM) to create these automatically at build time, in your case manifest creation will be a one-time job.

Here is how to use UMMM in your case. First create an `App.ini` file like this

```
Identity App.exe YourCompany.App "Application 1.0"
File TABCTL32.OCX
File MSWINSCK.OCX
File MSMAPI32.OCX
File FTP.OCX
File COMDLG32.OCX
# more OCXs/DLLs here...
```

"Compile" manifest with `UMMM.exe` like this

```
c:>UMMM.exe App.ini App.exe.manifest
```

Either place `App.exe.manifest` next to your `App.exe` or embed it as a resource with [`mt.exe`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa375649%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) from Windows SDK like this

```
c:>mt.exe -nologo -manifest App.exe.manifest -outputresource:App.exe;1
```

Unregister OCXs/DLLs (this is important) and test you application.