# How to handle talking to VB6 ActiveX dll that has OCX dependencies from a .NET WPF application

Tags: c#, com, vb6

I have a VB6 ActiveX dll that has a dependency on ComDlg32.ocx. This ActiveX dll is called from a .NET application.
The ActiveX dll has a public interface that has 1 method, which opens a form, which opens an Open File dialog (from ComDlg32.ocx). The .NET application has a button which will call this ActiveX dll method.

This all works when the ComDlg32.ocx and the ActiveX dll are both registered (via regsvr32), but I need to get this to work using RegFree COM, at least for the dependencies of the ActiveX dll. I have made a [manifest file](https://pastebin.com/V6FUJu9s) for this ActiveX dll but it doesn't seem to be getting read. ProcMon had no reference to the manifest file and sxstrace gave me no info (literally a blank text file when I parsed the etl file).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<assembly manifestVersion="1.0" xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
    <assemblyIdentity name="DeployArchitectureTest" version="1.0.0.0" type="win32" processorArchitecture="x86"/>
    <trustInfo xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
        <security>
            <requestedPrivileges>
                <requestedExecutionLevel level="asInvoker" uiAccess="false"/>
            </requestedPrivileges>
        </security>
    </trustInfo>
    <file name="COMDLG32.OCX">
        <typelib tlbid="{F9043C88-F6F2-101A-A3C9-08002B2F49FB}" version="1.2" flags="control,hasdiskimage" helpdir="" />
        <comClass clsid="{F9043C85-F6F2-101A-A3C9-08002B2F49FB}" tlbid="{F9043C88-F6F2-101A-A3C9-08002B2F49FB}" progid="MSComDlg.CommonDialog.1" threadingModel="Apartment" miscStatus="" miscStatusContent="recomposeonresize,onlyiconic,cantlinkinside,insideout,activatewhenvisible,invisibleatruntime,setclientsitefirst">
            <progid>MSComDlg.CommonDialog</progid>
        </comClass>
    </file>
</assembly>
```

I have tried an external manifest for the dll as well as embedding the manifest but still no luck. I must be missing something but all the information I can find talks about how to create a manifest file for an exe but no info about how to handle an ActiveX dll that has its own dependencies.

If anyone has any information then I would really appreciate it.

Comment: Have you defined redirect at application level (.exe)? also see this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12402461/403671

Comment: @SimonMourier I don't know how I would go about doing that. I did look at UMMM but wasn't able to get it working that way either, but maybe I was missing this redirect step. Any ideas on how to do that?

Comment: By redirect, I just meant have you done that at application level: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/interop/configure-net-framework-based-com-components-for-reg not component level. Or make sure the manifest is present in the exe. You can use Visual Studio and open it as a raw file: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/getfile/372689 you should see it as RT_MANIFEST

Comment: A regfree manifest in a DLL is technically possible, as long as it uses resource ID #2 and the DLL gets loaded by the operating system.  Neither is the case for a C# library, nothing you can do to change the way the CLR loads dependent assemblies.  Do keep in mind that you *must* install the VB6 runtime support modules, comdlg32.ocx should be part of it.

Comment: Don't you need an application manifest, instead of a DLL manifest?

Answer (score 2):

After some more research and being pointed in the right direction by @SimonMourier and @HansPassant, I managed to get this working.

I thought that a dll manifest would have been possible if I was using the resource ID #2 as @HansPassant mentioned, but I wasn't able to get it to work that way. No matter what I did, the dll manifest never seemed to be read.

I did however find that including all of the manifest data from what was the dll manifest into the exe manifest and making sure the exe had no embedded manifest allowed RegFree COM to work as expected. I was finding that Visual Studio was building my .NET exe with an embedded manifest, even though there was an app.manifest file as part of the project. I had to set the COM dll as 'isolated=true' in order for the manifest to be built as external.

So thank you both @SimonMourier and @HansPassant, both of your comments led me down the right path to figure it out.